# deviceToken is always null on Android with Parse.com

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform, push-notification

ParseInstallation class returns deviceToken as null and also in Parse.com Installation table the installation is saved as empty deviceToken.

Using

- Parse Android SDK 1.9.4
- Cordova version: 5.0.0
- com.phonegap.parsepushplugin (fork: https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin)

Android application class onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ParseCrashReporting.enable(getApplicationContext());
    Parse.initialize(this, "xx", "xx");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            String deviceToken = (String) ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");

            Log.d("my_app","DEVICE TOKEN: " + deviceToken);  // --> returns null string
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Tested on real Device or Emulator?

Comment: with real device (Samsung Galaxy Ace 4)

Comment: Did you solve this? @TuomasLaatikainen

Comment: @Rudy_TM My own answer below was the solution for me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the error. I had to change Parse permissions (allow adding fields) on Installation class and after that 'channels' field shown up and also deviceToken was saved.

Update:

You can confirm this on the app settings: 
Core > Data > _Installation > Security (button on toolbar)

[image: Security settings for the _Installation class]

By default it has access to create new fields but I had changed it.

Comment: Can you expound on what you mean by "change Parse permissions (allow adding fields) on Installation class"? Maybe a code snippet or a link to docs?

Comment: can you explain your solution

Comment: This answer explains what you did but not how. Please explain how.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you include your build flavor in the package name as well, I recently had this problem and didn't realize for a long time until I added that.

i.e com.packname.flavor{debug, release, etc.}

Comment: Where have you added build flavor in the package name ?